# JQuery onclick data attribute "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an issue pulling the data attributes out of an input when using onclick="javascript()" syntax.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I am trying:

https://jsfiddle.net/123umaon/2/

```
<div>
  <input onclick="Test();" type="button" value="test" data-section="thisSection"/>
</div>

function Test(){
var test = $(this).data('section');
alert(test);
}
```

I want to be able to pull the value of 'data-section' with the onclick action. But in my example it always comes back undefined.

Comment: This function doesn't receive any argument in your example... either you use a click handler and select the input. Or following your code, you pass the object as argument

Comment: It's like you see in those answers different are many to do it :) I voted for both of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#testOut').val("TEST TEST");

function Test(selector){
 var test = selector.data('section');
  alert(test);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input onclick="Test($(this));" type="button" value="test" data-section="thisSection"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference the current event. In the `Test()` function context, `this` refers to the window, instead of the DOM element.

```js
$('#testOut').val("TEST TEST");

function Test(){
var test = $(event.currentTarget).data('section');
alert(test);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input onclick="Test();" type="button" value="test" data-section="thisSection"/>
</div>
```

Note: The [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) variable I'm using here is frowned upon on new code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Test(btn){
var test = $(btn).attr("data-section");
alert(test);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input onclick="Test(this);" type="button" value="test" data-section="thisSection" />
</div>
```

The problem is with your selector. "$(this)" in your example returns a reference to the function Test.  Instead pass in this to the function and select off of the passed value.
Also, I would use the jQuery attr() funtion to set and return values on a custom property.

Answer (score 0):

Your function passes in the "Window" object, you'd need to refine what you're passing through.

For getting the data-section attribute, you can use the .getAttribute() method on the element. It works similarly to .setAttribute().

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp